# How do I set priviledges for /var/www and sftpd the right way?

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, ftp, vsftpd

Today I tried to setup my vps with `apache`. I installed it the standard way and did not configure anything at all.

I wanted to have 3 users (webdevelopers), that have access to subfolders in `www/html/testsvr/username`. So I created 3 users with home set to this path (one path for each user). The paths were created with the root user but I changed the privileges after.

I tried a lot now, but I think I don't understand what I did properly. With some of my tests I managed to login with the users (via filezilla on windows), but I didn't have the right to create files/folders. Right now i can't even connect and get the message:

```
sftpd "vsftpd: refusing to run with writeable root inside chroot.
```

Don't laugh about the following rights:

```
root@v-1:/var/www/html/testsvr# ls -l
total 12
drwxrwxrwx 2 daniel   webmaster 4096 Sep  7 20:08 daniel
drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data webmaster 4096 Sep  7 20:40 enes
drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data webmaster 4096 Sep  7 20:08 tobi
root@v-1:/var/www/html/testsvr# cd ..
root@v-1:/var/www/html# ls -l
total 52
drwxrwxrwx 5 www-data webmaster  4096 Sep  7 20:08 testsvr
```

For understanding: the master plan is, that every user has the group webmaster (already done) and every folder in testsvr should have rw rights for the group webmaster (so every of this 3 users)

Thought `drwxrwxrwx` means I got all rights, but that caused the ftp error I think.

Thank you so much for your help in advance!

EDIT:
I tried alot now. Just for you to understand:

I created a new user "test" with group "webmaster" and set the homepath tu var/www/html/testsvr/test
Permissions:
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     webmaster 4096 Sep  7 22:46 first
Now I can login, but I can't create files. If I give the group webmaster writeaccess i can't connect anymore.
Btw I turned on the setting to don't allow the ftp user to get outside his folder.

Comment: You mention `sftpd` here; do you mean you're using sftp and not ftp?  (I.E. SSH-tunneled FTP)

Comment: no I meant im using the package vsftpd sry

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use FTP and not, say, SSH tunneled SFTP which will be able to properly recognize the group level permissions in a better way (and not have chroot headaches)?  Are non-trusted users going to be FTPing here?